# Layer Styles Changing Properties?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layer-style

I have some saved layer styles. When I apply them to my document it changes the settings of the style. For instance - The Saved Style has a Stroke of 5. Yet when I apply the style it applies with a stroke of 17.

Why are the settings changing?

I am using PS CS5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably due to document PPI settings. In general, as ppi lowers measurements increase. 12pt type at 300ppi turns into 50pt type at 72ppi. The same holds true for styles.

It's always best to create your styles at a high resolution, that way you can simply scale them down. Scaling style down generally yields much better results than scaling them up.